# Sweden Phone Number Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I am using following regular expression for validating Sweden number

```
^(([+]46)((70[{0-9}])|(72[{0-9})])|(73[{0-9}])|(76[{0-9}]))([\d]{6}))$
```

I want my number to be in following format +46 70 5689 123 or +46705689123

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: And what's the problem exactly? Note that `[{0-9}]` will match `{` and `}` as well as digits.

Comment: the above expression does not allow spaces I want to allow a single space +46space70space1234space321

Comment: Add `\s?` between the groups or `\s*` if you want to allow infinite number or spaces.

Comment: Does the format have to be exactly those two or would something like `+46 705689123` be allowed? ie are the spaces independantly optional or are they all or none?

Comment: I want to allow a 07[0|2|3|6]1234321

Comment: Note that you should now also allow 079\d{7} (source: https://www.pts.se/upload/Beslut/Telefoni/2014/13-11805-beslut-andring-telefoninrplanen-07-serien-140407.pdf )

Comment: or just use https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp

Comment: This is actually a swedish mobile phone number regexp. Swedish landline phone numbers can be either (+46 or 0) + (7-9) numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The spaces (`\s*`) are missing in the regex:

```
^([+]46)\s*(7[0236])\s*(\d{4})\s*(\d{3})$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

https://www.debuggex.com/r/vG3FFsIeqa82QQRS

#### Discussion

I have replaced the parts like this one `70[{0-9}]` with something more readable: `7[0236]`.

Answer (score 4):

Why so many brackets?

```
^\+46 *7[0236] *\d{4} *\d{3}$
```

should do it.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of having a complete answer I'll add in to this thread.
Manoj, you wrote in the comment that you also want to allow numbers starting with 0 which the answer from Stephan (albeit great) doesn't cover.

You want to use

```
^(([+]46)\s*(7)|07)[02369]\s*(\d{4})\s*(\d{3})$
```

To allow:

- +46 7
- +467
- 07

Followed by 0/2/3/6/9, (a possible space), 4 digits, (a possible space), 3 digits

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vmavgWG9qhBBB0xt)

Comment: The first part handle the different starting variants. +46, 07 or if you want also 00467.
Simply change
([+]46)\s*(7)|07)
into
([+]46)\s*(7)|07|00467)

the | means "or" and denotes yet another possible variant. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this. Can probably be done neater, but it can handle that:

- Numbers can start with either +46 or 07 or 01.
- Might include a - like 0736-XXXXXX or 070-XXXXXXX
- White spaces can also occur anywhere (at least in my case, since we haven't really streamlined the inputs in the past).

> ^((([+]46)\s*((1|7)[0236]))|(0(1|7)[0236]))\s*(([-]|())\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*|([0-9]\s*([-]|()))\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*[0-9]\s*)$

Answer (score 0):

`^((((0{2}?)|(\+){1})46)|0)7[\d]{8}`

will work with 0046 708 777 666

[try it out](https://www.regextester.com/100159)

Answer (score 0):

/^07(0|2|3|6|9)\d{7}$/g

this will work for the local number starts with following initials: 070, 072, 073, 076, 079 Mobile phone networks
example: 076xxxxxxx
x will be the numeric

Answer (score 0):

I'll write this since the topic says "swedish phone number" and not "swedish **mobile** phone number". Despite it might not be exactly what the QS asked for.

Swedish land line numbers may have any number after the prefix, a lot of different whitspace setups depending on the length of the numbers and sometimes they are also written with hyphens.

```
Length 0+9 numbers
08-xxx xxx xx
0xx-xxx xx xx
0xxx-xx xx xx

Length 0+8 numbers
08-xxx xx xx
0xx-xx xx xx
0xxx-xxx xx

Length 0+7 numbers
08-xx xx xx
0xx-xxx xx

Length 0+9 numbers (Mobile)
07x-xxx xx xx
```

The prefix +46 or 00 could also be applied to those numbers. Also adding the notation the QS is asking for:

```
+46 70 5689 123
+46705689123
+46 85 68 91 23
```

This makes keeping track of all those whitespaces quite bothersome when writing a regexp. Thats why my suggestion would be to trim/remove all the spaces and/or hyphens and then run this regexp instead:

```
^(([+]46)|(0)|(00))(\d{7,9})$
```

In my opinion you will be better off by standardizing how you enter numbers in your database and not adding unneccesary whitespaces to avoid polluting the data anyways.

Sources:

https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefonnummer

https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_%C3%B6ver_svenska_riktnummer

Comment: Do not forget to remove ALL whitespaces